# Reserved IP address (classic) assign to SQL Database Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is is possible to assign a 
Reserved IP address (classic) to SQL Database? If so what is the best possible way to achieve this.

SQL Database name.database.windows.net

I have seen that it is possible to assign to an Virtual machine but not to a

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/reserved-ip-addresses/

SQL Database.

The only command i can see is

> New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName MyReservedIP –Location "Central
>   US"

I also have noted the following caption on  page when i was looking for a solution. Which makes me think that it is not possible.

> Can I use a reserved IP for all Azure services?
>
> Reserved IPs can only be used for VMs and cloud service instance roles
>   exposed through a VIP.

Comment: I don't understand the question - are you trying to assign an IP address to a SQL Database instance? Or are you just trying to allow traffic from your reserved IP address from your cloud service? Please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: Assign an ip to a sql database in Azure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Database is a multi-tenant service - you cannot assign any IP address to it. You may only access it by its `<yourname>.database.windows.net` URL.

You *can* tell SQL Database about your own IP addresses (such as ones assigned to your VM's), to allow traffic from those VMs to access SQL Database, but you cannot an IP address to SQL Database instances.